# How to add two different sized vectors VHDL

Tags: vector, vhdl, addition

Hello I would like to ask, how could I add two vectors in VHDL, which one of them is 7 downto 0 and the other one is 8 downto 0. I tried something like this, but it does not work. Thank you in advance.

```
IS_CARRY <= '0' & (IN1 + IN2)
```

Comment: Try `IS_CARRY <= (('0' & IN1) + IN2)`, assuming that `IN1` is the narrower bus.

Comment: I solved it. I have to include `use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;`  Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to extend the shorter vector to 9 bits and then do the addition.

Declarations:

```
signal in1 : UNSIGNED(7 downto 0);
signal in2 : UNSIGNED(8 downto 0);
signal res : UNSIGNED(8 downto 0);
```

Example:

```
res <= ('0' & in1) + in2;
```

---

It's not recommended to use `STD_LOGIC_ARITH` and `STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED`. Use `NUMERIC_STD` instead. Doing arithmetic on `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`s is no good style. Use the types `SIGNED` and `UNSIGNED` for this purpose.

Comment: The arithmetic operations from `numeric_std` accept to work with 2 vectors of different lengths, so there should be no need to extend them manually.